When running my Next.js app, the oktaAuth instance is undefined in the HomePage component, preventing proper authentication with Okta
/my-nextjs-app

├── /contexts│   
    └── UserContext.tsx
├── /pages│   
  ├── _app.tsx│
  └── index.tsx
├── /container
│   └── HomeContainer.tsx
├── /utils
│   └── oktaConfig.ts
├── /styles
│   └── globals.css
└── package.json

HomePage Component (/pages/index.tsx):
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { OktaAuth } from "@okta/okta-auth-js";

const HomePage: React.FC<{ oktaAuth: OktaAuth }> = ({ oktaAuth }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      if (!oktaAuth) {
        console.error("oktaAuth is undefined");
        return;
      }
      
      const isAuthenticated = await oktaAuth.isAuthenticated();
      console.log("isAuthenticated", isAuthenticated);
      
      if (!isAuthenticated) {
        await oktaAuth.signInWithRedirect(); // Redirect to Okta SSO login page
      } else {
        try {
          const accessToken = await oktaAuth.getAccessToken();
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching user info or access token:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  return <div></div>;
};

export default HomePage;

MyApp Component (/pages/_app.tsx):
import { AppProps } from "next/app";
import { UserProvider } from "../contexts/UserContext";
import { OktaAuth } from "@okta/okta-auth-js";
import { Security } from "@okta/okta-react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { oktaConfig } from "../utils/oktaConfig";
import "../styles/globals.css";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const oktaAuth = new OktaAuth(oktaConfig);

  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <Security oktaAuth={oktaAuth} restoreOriginalUri={() => {}}>
        <Component {...pageProps} oktaAuth={oktaAuth} />
      </Security>
    </UserProvider>
  );
}

export default MyApp;

`Problem Description:
When I run the application, the oktaAuth instance appears to be undefined in the HomePage component. I am trying to check if the user is authenticated and redirect to the Okta login page if not, but I'm not sure if I'm implementing the Security wrapper correctly or if I'm missing something in the setup.
"@okta/okta-auth-js": "^7.8.1",
"@okta/okta-react": "^6.9.0",
"next": "^14.1.2",
"next-auth": "^4.24.5",`
How can I properly pass the oktaAuth instance to the HomePage component? Are there any best practices I should follow when integrating Okta with Next.js? Is there anything else I might be missing in my setup?
"@okta/okta-auth-js": "^7.8.1",
"@okta/okta-react": "^6.9.0",
"next": "^14.1.2",
"next-auth": "^4.24.5",

